# Should I change the AMP url? (when updating the url for the page itself?)

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url, amp, path

Let's say I have a page under `www.example.com/some/path`, and its AMP version is under `www.example.com/some/path/amp`.

If I change the path of the page, let's say to `www.example.com/other/path`, should I change the path of the AMP as well, for example to this: `www.example.com/other/path/amp`?

In other words, are there any disadvantages to have one fixed AMP url for a page, for all the page lifetime, without ever changing it, even though the page's url (the canonical) is changing?

I've tried to search around the web and in google documentation, and all I have found is guidelines which say that I should have a redirect whenever the AMP URL is changed (basically when moving from old site to new site which doesn't supports the old URL structure).

The point is that I don't want to get to the situation when I even need the redirect, since I will always have the same AMP URL.

Of course the amp page will have the updated page URL as the canonical, and as I understand it, the SEO power is generated by the the URL of the page and not the AMP version of the page.

So are there any advantages to update the URL of the AMP as well?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any advantage of updating the URL of the AMP page whenever the original URL changes. All you have to do (as you have rightly mentioned) is to change the canonical on both the pages to reflect this. I did a quick check on AMP's official documentation. No specific guidelines were present asking one to establish **any relation between URL patterns** of AMP and non-AMP versions.

https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/discovery/